# Get the Message Type in JMS - IBM MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am building an application which reveives message from a Message Queue , Process it and and send the generated response to another queue. I have successfully built the same.

But, before sending the msg I must get the Correlation ID, Message ID and Message Type from it, So that I will be able to set these in my generated response msg as well.

I have fetched CorrelationID and Message ID using the below code.

```
               Message Requestmessage = ReceiveMessage(queueName);
               String correlationID = Requestmessage.getJMSCorrelationID();
               String messageID = Requestmessage.getJMSMessageID();
```

How will I get the Message Type. There are 5 types of Messages as far as I understood.
                    1. Text Message
                    2. Byte Message
                    3. Stream Message
                    4. Object Message
                    5. Map Message
All I need is, to find out which type my "Requestmessage" belongs to.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can't you just use instanceof to check the type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. I used instanceof keyword.

```
        if(Requestmessage instanceof TextMessage )
        {
             //
        }

        if(Requestmessage instanceof BytesMessage)
        {
            //
        }
        if(Requestmessage instanceof ObjectMessage)
        {
            //          
        }
        if(Requestmessage instanceof StreamMessage)
        {
            //
        }
```

Comment: Sad. But seems to be the only solution. :-(